# Jsoup css selector

Tags: html, css, jsoup

I have this html code:

```
<div class="last-minute">
<span>Modulo:</span>4-3-3<p>Mandorlini durante questa sosta confida di recuperare
Juanito Gomez e Cirigliano, attualmente fermi ai box. Non preoccupa Hallfredsson  
sostituito a Genova per un taglio al capo. </p><div class="squalificati">
<span>Squalificati :</span>-</div><div class="indisponibili"><span>Indisponibili : 
</span> 
<div><strong><a title="Cirigliano" href="../../../../calciatore/VERONA 
HELLAS/Cirigliano">Cirigliano</a></strong>: Lesione distrattiva al flessore destro</div>
<div><strong><a title="Juanito " href="../../../../calciatore/VERONA HELLAS/Juanito 
">Juanito </a></strong>: Lesione distrattiva al bicipite femorale destro</div> </div> 
<div class="dubbio"><span>In dubbio :</span>-</div><div class="diffidati">
<span>Ballottaggi :</span>Jankovic 60% - Martinho 40%</div><div style='float: 
left;margin-bottom: 8px;font-style: italic;color: #929292;line-height: 14px;width: 
168px;'>Aggiornamento:12/11/2013 12:09:36</div>
```

I would like to get that "4-3-3" just after this code :`<span>Modulo:</span>` (2nd line).
How can i get it using the css selector in jsoup? Thank you.

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: I don't know which selector use because "4-3-3" is directly inside the <div class="last-minute"> element, so how can i get only that part, excluding all the rest of the tags?? @FabianBarney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `ownText()` method of the Element class (see [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29)), which selects only the text owned directly by the element and ignores its child tags.

For example:

```
String html = "<div class='last-minute'><span>Modulo:</span>4-3-3<p>Mandorlini....";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

System.out.println(doc.select("div.last-minute").first().ownText());
```

Will output:

```
4-3-3
```